# Variable not expanding in query

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

I am unable to get the "$optioncodesOut" variable to expand in the "$showshop" select statement. This worked just fin in my old mysql_query() but I am not able to get it to work here. I have verified that the is actually an output.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
$radius = "50";     //("'. $radius .'")
$lat = "33.776";    //("'. $lat .'")
$lon = "-95.7128";  //("'. $lon .'")
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// select statment
$optioncodes = 'SELECT zip_code, latitude, longitude, statename, city,
    ROUND((ACOS((SIN(33.776/57.2958) * SIN(latitude/57.2958)) +
    (COS(("'. $lat .'")/57.2958) * COS(latitude/57.2958) *
    COS(longitude/57.2958 - ("'. $lon .'")/57.2958))))
    * 3963) AS distance
    from tblzipcode
    WHERE (latitude >= ("'. $lat .'") - (("' . $radius . '")/111))
    And (latitude <= ("'. $lat .'") + (("' . $radius . '")/111))
    AND (longitude >= ("'. $lon .'") - (("' . $radius . '")/111))
    AND (longitude <= ("'. $lon .'") + (("' . $radius . '")/111))
    ORDER BY distance';
$result2 = $conn->query($optioncodes);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) {
    $optioncodesOut = $row2['zip_code'] . ",";
    echo $optioncodesOut;
  }

$showshop = 'select id, attn, addr1, addr2, addr3, city, state, country, zip, phone_number, fax, web_site_url, delaerwebid, ARCUSTO_ID, CUSTNO as dealer from DEALERLOCATOR where zip in ("'.$optioncodesOut.'")';
$result = $conn->query($showshop);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<br />' . $row['zip'] . '&nbsp;' . $row['attn'] . $row['ARCUSTO_ID'] . '<br />';
    } 
   }
  }

echo '<br />'.$showshop;
?>
```

Current output of "$optioncodesOut"

```
75425,75486,75421,75473,75460,75461,75470,75462,75462,75411,75477,74738,74759,75488,75446,74727,75416,74743,75450,75492,74723,74723,75443,75468,75438,75469,75441,74756,75434,75435,75432,75415,75449,74726,74760,75496,75481,
```

As you can see the only zip code displayed in "$optioncodesOut" is "75481".

```
select id, attn, addr1, addr2, addr3, city, state, country, zip, phone_number, fax, web_site_url, delaerwebid, ARCUSTO_ID, CUSTNO as dealer from DEALERLOCATOR where zip in ("75481,")
```

Comment: You are having a concatenation issue. Change this line to read: `$optioncodesOut .= $row2['zip_code'] . ",";` . You are missing the concatenation operator. Otherwise each time you loop, you are overriding the $optioncodesOut variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's a concatenation issue.
Try changing this line:

```
$optioncodesOut = $row2['zip_code'] . ",";
```

as follows:

```
$optioncodesOut = $optioncodesOut . $row2['zip_code'] . ",";
```

Comment: What about just adding the . concatenation operator before the equal (=) like this `$optioncodesOut .= $row2['zip_code'] . ",";` . The dot just saves the day.

Comment: Yup. I am not used to work with PHP and you're absolutely right :)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the quick answer!